# Android: Set spacing to left of scrollbar in gridview

Tags: gridview, scrollbar, android-layout

I have a grid view with scroll bars permanently displayed. When i set the android:paddingRight property (of the GridView) to say 10dip the vertical scroll bar is shifted to the left as well.

I don't want the scroll bar to shift to the left, i purely want extra white space between the scroll bar and the grid views tiled elements.

Not to say that this isn't expected behaviour, but is there a way of adding space to the left of scroll bar without having to either:

- Specify custom drawables for the scrollbar elements.
- Add the spacing to the Grid Views tiles (i.e my custom layouts).

Android 2.2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah
found that the following controls the behaviour i was looking to control.

```
<GridView 
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
/>
```

Comment: Was able to make the change apply globally by adding the property to the theme.xml <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideInset</item> along with <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item> to permenantly display them.